# Error when creating a virtual field inside a model

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm having a hard time setting up a virtual field in one of my model. I've been setting virtualfields like this in all of my models without any issue. However, for some reason I can't figure out, it's not working at all in this model.

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'databases WHERE id = `DataSourceName`.`database_id`) AS `DataSourceName__databa' at line 1
```

Model:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * DataSourceName Model
 *
 * @property Database $Database
 */
class DataSourceName extends AppModel {
    public $virtualFields = array(
            'database' => 'SELECT name FROM databases WHERE id = DataSourceName.database_id',
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Database' => array(
            'className' => 'Database',
            'foreignKey' => 'database_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_source_names(
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  database_id INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  created_by INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  modified_by INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Update 1**

SQL failing:

```
(SELECT name FROM databases WHERE id = `DataSourceName`.`database_id`) AS `DataSourceName__database`
```

Comment: I suggest you to read more what actually a virtual field is..

Comment: Share the actual SQL code that is failing. My guess the problem is that the `id` column in your statement is ambiguous. Try ` WHERE databases.id = DataSourceName.database_id`

Comment: @AgRizzo see my updates for the failing SQL. I tried your suggestion and it didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using for the SQL:

```
SELECT name FROM my_db.databases WHERE id = `DataSourceName`.`database_id`
```

Note the database name prefix (ie. `my_db`) in front of the table `databases`. Probably due to `databases` being a reserved word.

Final Model:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * DataSourceName Model
 *
 * @property Database $Database
 */
class DataSourceName extends AppModel {

    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);

        $fields = get_class_vars('DATABASE_CONFIG');

        $this->virtualFields['database'] = sprintf(
                'SELECT name FROM %s.databases WHERE id = DataSourceName.database_id', $fields['default']['database']
        );


    }

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Database' => array(
            'className' => 'Database',
            'foreignKey' => 'database_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```